# how to replace data list Type value with dictionary value based on matching name

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary and list of data and

1. I need only data from list of data `lstData`, if `Type` is exist in dictionary.
2. and I need to replace `Type` name of `lstData` with name in dictionary. `type1` with "X" and `type3` with `type3`.

   ```
   var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "type1", "X" }, { "type3", "type3" } };

       var lstData = new List<Data>
       {
           new Data {Name = "N1", Type = "type1"},
           new Data {Name = "N1", Type = "type2"},
           new Data {Name = "N2", Type = "type3"},
       };
   ```

With below query I am able to achieve part 1), how to do part 2) ?

```
        var x = lstData.Where(a => new List<string>(dictionary.Keys).Any(b => b == a.Type));
```

Expected output should be,

```
x = new List<Data>
        {
            new Data {Name = "N1", Type = "X"},
            new Data {Name = "N2", Type = "type3"},
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ContainsKey` will be more efficient, especially for large datasets.

You can then use `Select` to create your new `Data` objects:

```
var x = listData
    .Where(d => dictionary.ContainsKey(d.Type)) // Part 1
    .Select(d => new Data { Name = d.Name, Type = dictionary[d.Type] }) // Part 2
    .ToList();
```